# Как получить product id уже в header.php в bitrix?

Tags: битрикс

В битриксе новичек, необходимо для кода счетчика передать id товара в js который должен стоять сразу после body. Не могу найти как взять id товара из header.php - когда он выполняется блок с товаром еще не загружен.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, пишем функцию в header.php и запускаем как отложенную

```
$APPLICATION->AddBufferContent('имяфункции');
```

нужные параметры передаем из любого блока описав их в component_epilog.php

```
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('.......') //передаем параметры
```

потом в функции которая в header.php считываем нужное:

```
$APPLICATION->GetPageProperty('......');
```